# How to pass an argument to a perl script

Tags: linux, perl, at-command

```
 my @return = `at now +3 days -f test2.pl myargument 2>&1`;
```

How do I pass that myargument to my script test2.pl? In that code it returns an error.

Comment: This does not seem to be a problem with Perl, but with your usage of the `at` command. To make debugging easier, it may be better to rephrase this question without any references to Perl. e.g. try executing `echo hello world` in two minutes directly from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for `at` on my system, it reads bourne shell commands to be executed from from the file specified with `-f` or STDIN.

As such, the following should do the trick:

```
`printf %s 'test2.pl myargument' | at now +3 days 2>&1`;
```

Comment: In my script i need to send an email which needs to be sent in a later time handled by the at command. In your solution which works, it sends the email first then create the job. Please help

Comment: I bet you actually used `\`test2.pl myargument | at now +3 days 2>&1\``